# Edit multiple xml files in different folders

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to edit two xml files in different directories. One called test.xml is in C:\Users\user\Desktop. The other one is also called test.xml and is located in C:\Users\user\Desktop\test. I am trying to change values in both of them.

```
import os
import xml.dom.minidom as md
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop"):
    for file in files
        file = md.parse("test.xml")
        file.getElementsByTagName("size")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue="Large"
        file.getElementsByTagName("weight")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue="30oz"
    with open("test.xml", "w") as fs:
        fs.write(file.toxml())
        fs.close()
```

This only edits the first file but it doesn't edit the others. Here is the XML for both of them, if that will help.

test.xml in C:\Users\user\Desktop

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<food_list>
    <fruit>
        <name>Strawberry</name>
        <size>Medium</size>
        <weight>19oz</weight>
        <id>S001</id>
    </fruit>
</food_list>
```

test.xml in C:\Users\user\Desktop\test

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<food_list>
    <fruit>
        <name>Apple</name>
        <size>Small</size>
        <weight>19oz</weight>
        <id>A001</id>
    </fruit>
</food_list>
```

What can I do so it will edit both files? I'm really stuck here so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a "how can I `os.walk()` into subfolders" question, not an XML question? (litmus test: Does the question change when you take out the XML part? If not, research the underlying question.)

Comment: @Tomalak It does not know that his mistake is completely outside the xml part. Because in Order to know it, it has to know the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

First: You did indent wrongly.
The "with open" stuff must be one indentation deeper, so it gets also iterated.
Second: you just used "test.xml" as the file name, but not the result of your os.walk call.

```
import os
import xml.dom.minidom as md
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop"):
    for filename in files
        if filename.endswith(".xml")
            file = md.parse(root+"\\"+filename)
            file.getElementsByTagName("size")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue="Large"
            file.getElementsByTagName("weight")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue="30oz"
            with open(root+"\\"+filename, "w") as fs:
                fs.write(file.toxml())
                fs.close()
```

What you did was creating "file" for all files, but saving only the last

Comment: sorry, I did not get the target filename completely. Must be root+"\\" too (edited)